# How do I TypeScript this object/array?

Tags: typescript

My React app has a data structure which is structured like this:

```js
    data = {
      2021-03-01: {
                    "date": 1st March,
                    "value": 17
                   },
      2021-03-02: {
                    "date": 2nd March,
                    "value": 19
                   },
              .
              .
              .
      2021-03-09: {
                    "date": 9th March,
                    "value": 15
                   }
    }
```

How do I define this in TypeScript?  I don't know how to handle the fact that the keys are different for each item.

Comment: Well that's not valid JS, so it won't work at all. The solution to this problem is to fix your data so it makes sense

Comment: As far as I know you cannot have keys which are not either strings (which makes it an object) or integers. Consider restructuring your data (also have in mind whether or not the key is unique)

Comment: @guyaloni just strings and symbols. Numbers get automatically converted to strings in plain JS, and Typescript won't let you use non-string keys.

Comment: BTW, did you check your snippet? It gives an error. See my previous comment.

Comment: The paste probably went wrong. Anyway, check this: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=19&pc=2#code/C4TwDgpgBAIghsOUC8UBKEDGB7ATgEwB4BnYXASwDsBzAGigG8AoKVqfBCALilIpoDcLNgDc4AGwCu3KJUkBbAEYRcQgL4A+JkxyVS7BHB7xEKRsNYByAEwAGawEYAtLYDMLh5Z7M2vqACIOYAh-HksHfQBZOFxMAAtLWgs-fzEpEJ4HAHZktSTfG3tnNxdrL3M-NkDOUKgbSnwoaNiE-MqAtOlahwBOXLarO0cXd1se8p926uDayx7gOKaY+MTk31SJLsyAVlymNSA

Comment: Thank you Mosh Feu.  Yes, the paste went wrong and I didn't post the full thing, but I can work out what I need from your answer!

Answer (score 1):

Here you have safe type for your object:

```js
type PrependNextNum<A extends Array<unknown>> = A["length"] extends infer T
    ? ((t: T, ...a: A) => void) extends (...x: infer X) => void
    ? X
    : never
    : never;

type EnumerateInternal<A extends Array<unknown>, N extends number> = {
    0: A;
    1: EnumerateInternal<PrependNextNum<A>, N>;
}[N extends A["length"] ? 0 : 1];

type Enumerate<N extends number> = EnumerateInternal<[], N> extends (infer E)[]
    ? E
    : never;


type ZeroRequired = 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9;

type AddZero<T extends number> = T extends ZeroRequired ? `${0}${T}` : T;

type AddSt<T extends NumberString<number>> = `${T}st`;

type MakeString<T extends number | string> = `${T}`;

type Month = MakeString<AddZero<Exclude<Enumerate<13>, 0>>>;

type Day = MakeString<AddZero<Exclude<Enumerate<32>, 0>>>;

type Months = 'January' | 'February' | 'March';



type NumberString<T extends number> = `${T}`;

type Year = `${NumberString<number>}${NumberString<number>}${NumberString<number>}${NumberString<number>}`;

type DataKey = `${Year}-${Month}-${Day}`;

type GetDay<T extends DataKey> = T extends `${string}-${Month}-${infer D}` ? D : `${number}`;

type GetMonth<T extends DataKey> = T extends `${string}-${infer M}-${Day}` ? M : `${number}`;

type MapMonth<T extends NumberString<number>> =
    T extends '01'
    ? 'January' : T extends '02'
    ? 'February' : T extends '03'
    ? 'March' : never;

type ConvertToMonth<T extends DataKey> = MapMonth<GetMonth<T>>;

type RemoveLeadZero<T extends GetDay<DataKey>> = T extends `0${infer N}` ? N : T

type MakeDate<T extends DataKey> = `${AddSt<RemoveLeadZero<GetDay<T>>>} ${ConvertToMonth<T>}`

type Base = Record<DataKey, { date: MakeDate<DataKey>, value: number }>


const data = {
    '2021-03-01': {
        "date": "1st March",
        "value": 17,
    },
    '2021-03-02': {
        "date": '2st March',
        "value": 19,
    },

} as const;

type Data = typeof data

type Values<T> = T[keyof T]

// should be allowed to proceed
type Test = Values<keyof Data extends DataKey ? {
    [P in keyof Data]: P extends DataKey ? Data[P]['date'] extends MakeDate<P> ? true : false : false
} : false> extends true ? 'allowed' : 'disallowed'
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACgThSA7AJgOQgD2GgrgWwB4BBKLYCVAZymLjgEMRDckBrJAewHckA%20PlAC8tANoAiADaUA5sAAW4gLplslFDQCWSAGYQ4UACoAoKGagB%20KAAprwAFxGANFAB07ho%20IBKYYIBunJoovuTqNNburpiO2noGABq%20QgFBKKbmVgkZZo5IEP76OVB5BfoA3MbGoJBQAKJIBPoMFACSSBRwSAySJKoU1LT0TCzsXLx8Lmj94VCN%20ABG%20oIiAN7FAAxeleZQAIyODU2MbR363b3wiOoY2HhExJNQaHyVAL6i02GDxBLSSHJFCorBsSvslJVquBoEd8M0KIQvmpBvMlnAVvV5vCIO1OhdCKIlFNBN8NDY4vp6t5CcUrHViqVCnBIVDagAtfScABKEAAjrhNAgUMJ9lAAD5QABM4qgAGYZQAWGUAVhlADYZQB2GUADhlAE5ITVoMQUCgOXBOIRDDMUQQ0RibaSaBbuXyBULLFAAAYAElWGze-sMb29YMMRuhtDNAGVgNbbWT7mi43BtDJCKjlhi-asQ1RgN7I7UALIMNgQVPphPOub2ykSgtpgE54Oh4vQEucDryEVlitVgEkM2uwh1TAAY0kuBQEDHWJOc72sqeGwEryqxqgABEmH3y5XgM2M6bzZyx5Pp7P58cWnPZZLV%20uO1Auz2aCIAOQAKQYjQYcAgJ%20MqfgAYhACxwLgAFASBZZwBO8ifiyrLQMm%20iDhmTrImSWboiKuYhkWm5RgAmhAAEEf66FwJhmb1uiQarDRdF4XwTEsUe1ZsRxDGsQx7HEahO4tAwADSEAgFRqzkQBbwALT%20m%20CgKf6u4gO2JG1AA4hAwDqTWOE0LuwDiZJjqJjQuZNumqmrMp8h2RSBjbqGXrbmCuZ4Zpwm6cADmGQMZImWZIAWbW1lcQCTm6JSJZ2epblWCWnn%20t5QlbmWYABdhQU0Jxx70Ys2bCMUuWzJ%20Gx7J%20tJQD%20f7QYBwGOOVgyVZKNW7FYYEQVBMHNUYll1RssqdZkdXwYhA35EyL4AMLdkywCGJwOVDSFElhfu2XdgohB%20TlAgvjy%20CcIUAAyFFnpagWzH5BkbeZ4VGT6Gz%20s5zxJc84ZaZ2B4mXOrXBaJm2tqsp5xoQJ1nRAl0MNdVr3SMhjrm8UD%20gtSBLSth2hr9UAAEIMFQ0AiDyE6cHAKCEI9IAuKsUAoHejj9hAAM0yD5kuP4PS4BAeQMVAbx8FUxgU0gBaM6JIrrLsn6Shskp7PJI0q9Vjiy7s5jiEzFDiI44h7JLk2KE4xS7OIPPThA%20v7JqZu7G8DvmPLivK6riufhr5va7rNuOPLxsAVNzta1Alu8-7%20z6qHQtm8YaPE1A4sFi%20IUisanA6FLpn4wAapHVDWo6ogViAWdGEoVQAPTV1AVDyJwuCSMKSxQD0kg8BAwrAJwUBgJaE4QN3wmGBAksiAX1tF2XFfp7WtNeprZiiDAUDaFAs-ZyFSiOGvC%20c1JVghavSiiJ%20fufiotas%20zMCCFYR582COg9CTL9vxACcf5IJMki9T9oDdQ7l3FAA0L6aCoCA7g3dPxAA)