# Typescript string date type definition

Tags: typescript

How to type date string from json api ?

I want to create type for my api Response. Here is my api json response

```json
{
    "startDate": "2021-10-02T00:00:00Z",
    "endDate": "2021-10-02T23:59:00Z",
    "title": "My first event",
    "id": 1
}
```

Actually I define type like that:

```
type EventApiItem = {
    startDate: string,
    endDate: string,
    title: string
}
```

And I use my type like that

```
var eventItem: EventApiItem = {
   startDate: response.startDate,
   endDate: response.startDate,
   title: response.title
}
```

**Is there a way to be more specific for date string ?**

Answer (score 0):

```js
type EventApiItem = {
    startDate: Date,
    endDate: Date,
    title: string
}
```

Comment: Seems wrong because if i do that:  `type Test = { date: Date }` and then i declare a variable like that: `var test : Test = { date: "2021-10-02T23:59:00Z"}` I got following error: `Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Date'`

Comment: `var test : Test = { date: new Date("2021-10-02T23:59:00Z")}`, you need to convert string to date

Comment: Yep ok so my api return type need to be a string.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a very specific way to do it.

Take a look an [my article](https://catchts.com/dates) and [this closed question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66563064/how-do-i-typescript-this-object-array#answer-66564065)

```js
type PrependNextNum<A extends Array<unknown>> = A["length"] extends infer T
    ? ((t: T, ...a: A) => void) extends (...x: infer X) => void
    ? X
    : never
    : never;

type EnumerateInternal<A extends Array<unknown>, N extends number> = {
    0: A;
    1: EnumerateInternal<PrependNextNum<A>, N>;
}[N extends A["length"] ? 0 : 1];

type Enumerate<N extends number> = EnumerateInternal<[], N> extends (infer E)[]
    ? E
    : never;


type ZeroRequired = 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9;

type AddZero<T extends number> = T extends ZeroRequired ? `${0}${T}` : T;

type AddSt<T extends NumberString<number>> = `${T}st`;

type MakeString<T extends number | string> = `${T}`;

type Month = MakeString<AddZero<Exclude<Enumerate<13>, 0>>>;

type Day = MakeString<AddZero<Exclude<Enumerate<32>, 0>>>;

type Months = 'January' | 'February' | 'March';



type NumberString<T extends number> = `${T}`;

type Year = `${NumberString<number>}${NumberString<number>}${NumberString<number>}${NumberString<number>}`;

type DataKey = `${Year}-${Month}-${Day}`;

type GetDay<T extends DataKey> = T extends `${string}-${Month}-${infer D}` ? D : `${number}`;

type GetMonth<T extends DataKey> = T extends `${string}-${infer M}-${Day}` ? M : `${number}`;

type MapMonth<T extends NumberString<number>> =
    T extends '01'
    ? 'January' : T extends '02'
    ? 'February' : T extends '03'
    ? 'March' : never;

type ConvertToMonth<T extends DataKey> = MapMonth<GetMonth<T>>;

type RemoveLeadZero<T extends GetDay<DataKey>> = T extends `0${infer N}` ? N : T

type MakeDate<T extends DataKey> = `${AddSt<RemoveLeadZero<GetDay<T>>>} ${ConvertToMonth<T>}`

type Base = Record<DataKey, { date: MakeDate<DataKey>, value: number }>


const data = {
    '2021-03-01': {
        "date": "1st March",
        "value": 17,
    },
    '2021-03-02': {
        "date": '2st March',
        "value": 19,
    },

} as const;

type Data = typeof data

type Values<T> = T[keyof T]

// should be allowed to proceed
type Test = Values<keyof Data extends DataKey ? {
    [P in keyof Data]: P extends DataKey ? Data[P]['date'] extends MakeDate<P> ? true : false : false
} : false> extends true ? 'allowed' : 'disallowed'
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACgThSA7AJgOQgD2GgrgWwB4BBKLYCVAZymLjgEMRDckBrJAewHckA%20PlAC8tANoAiADaUA5sAAW4gLplslFDQCWSAGYQ4UACoAoKGagB%20KAAprwAFxGANFAB07ho%20IBKYYIBunJoovuTqNNburpiO2noGABq%20QgFBKKbmVgkZZo5IEP76OVB5BfoA3MbGoJBQAKJIBPoMFACSSBRwSAySJKoU1LT0TCzsXLx8Lmj94VCN%20ABG%20oIiAN7FAAxeleZQAIyODU2MbR363b3wiOoY2HhExJNQaHyVAL6i02GDxBLSSHJFCorBsSvslJVquBoEd8M0KIQvmpBvMlnAVvV5vCIO1OhdCKIlFNBN8NDY4vp6t5CcUrHViqVCnBIVDagAtfScABKEAAjrhNAgUMJ9lAAD5QABM4qgAGYZQAWGUAVhlADYZQB2GUADhlAE5ITVoMQUCgOXBOIRDDMUQQ0RibaSaBbuXyBULLFAAAYAElWGze-sMb29YMMRuhtDNAGVgNbbWT7mi43BtDJCKjlhi-asQ1RgN7I7UALIMNgQVPphPOub2ykSgtpgE54Oh4vQEucDryEVlitVgEkM2uwh1TAAY0kuBQEDHWJOc72sqeGwEryqxqgABEmH3y5XgM2M6bzZyx5Pp7P58cWnPZZLV%20uO1Auz2aCIAOQAKQYjQYcAgJ%20MqfgAYhACxwLgAFASBZZwBO8ifiyrLQMm%20iDhmTrImSWboiKuYhkWm5RgAmhAAEEf66FwJhmb1uiQarDRdF4XwTEsUe1ZsRxDGsQx7HEahO4tAwADSEAgFRqzkQBbwALT%20m%20CgKf6u4gO2JG1AA4hAwDqTWOE0LuwDiZJjqJjQuZNumqmrMp8h2RSBjbqGXrbmCuZ4Zpwm6cADmGQMZImWZIAWbW1lcQCTm6JSJZ2epblWCWnn%20t5QlbmWYABdhQU0Jxx70Ys2bCMUuWzJ%20Gx7J%20tJQD%20f7QYBwGOOVgyVZKNW7FYYEQVBMHNUYll1RssqdZkdXwYhA35EyL4AMLdkywCGJwOVDSFElhfu2XdgohB%20TlAgvjy%20CcIUAAyFFnpagWzH5BkbeZ4VGT6Gz%20s5zxJc84ZaZ2B4mXOrXBaJm2tqsp5xoQJ1nRAl0MNdVr3SMhjrm8UD%20gtSBLSth2hr9UAAEIMFQ0AiDyE6cHAKCEI9IAuKsUAoHejj9hAAM0yD5kuP4PS4BAeQMVAbx8FUxgU0gBaM6JIrrLsn6Shskp7PJI0q9Vjiy7s5jiEzFDiI44h7JLk2KE4xS7OIPPThA%20v7JqZu7G8DvmPLivK6riufhr5va7rNuOPLxsAVNzta1Alu8-7%20z6qHQtm8YaPE1A4sFi%20IUisanA6FLpn4wAapHVDWo6ogViAWdGEoVQAPTV1AVDyJwuCSMKSxQD0kg8BAwrAJwUBgJaE4QN3wmGBAksiAX1tF2XFfp7WtNeprZiiDAUDaFAs-ZyFSiOGvC%20c1JVghavSiiJ%20fufiotas%20zMCCFYR582COg9CTL9vxACcf5IJMki9T9oDdQ7l3FAA0L6aCoCA7g3dPxAA)